# EF 5 Enable migrations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I have not much experience with programing and I am using EF 5 when I attempt to run the "enable migrations" command I am getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo
>   especificado

I have two versions of Visual Studio 2013 - one is the Professional edition and the other is the Express Edition 2013 Update 4, in both versions when I try to Enable Migrations I get the exception.

I did download shell isolated, as well as Visual Studio Update 2 and 4,
and I continue to get the error message.

Comment: If you have trouble migrating  a) start a new project b) place your files (.cs, .cshtml, .css, etc)  in that project[or copy & paste them in, if need be] ......

Comment: what version of the .net framework is your project targeting?

Comment: Is  aspnet mvc 4. and i have allredy tray to copy and paste and inciete another project

Comment: the net framwork that i am targeting is 4